# Is the sentence "we are playing with my friend" correct if the "we" only means my friend and me?

Tags: personal-pronouns

My friend says it should be "My friend and I are playing", but I think "We are playing with my friend" is correct too. Is it?

Comment: This is as much a logic question as grammar: If there are ***three*** of you: *two* friends *and yourself*, then your construction "We are playing with my friend" applies - ***if*** there are *only* the ***two*** of you, *then* your friend is correct, as "we are playing with my friend" *directly* implicates the existence of *a "we"* ***beyond*** *you and your friend*, as it's that "we" who "are playing with my friend". I'm not sure if this really fits here.

Answer (score 3):

Your friend is right. "We are playing with my friend" signals that at least two people are playing with your friend, so at least three people total are playing. You could say "I am playing with my friend" or "My friend and I are playing" or We are playing."